# Swift generic property as value for generic closure

Tags: swift, generics, mocking, alamofire, swift-protocols

Im been spinning my wheels on this one getting no where for a while. I am trying to create an Alamofire mock class for serializable objects.

I have a protocol:

```
protocol AlamofireManagerInterface {
    func apiRequest<T: ResponseObjectSerializable>(withMethod method: Alamofire.Method,
        forURLString URLString: URLStringConvertible,
        withParameters parameters: [String: AnyObject]?,
        withEncoding encoding: ParameterEncoding,
        withHeaders headers: [String: String]?,
        completion completionHandler: (Response<T, NSError> -> Void))
}
```

This allows me to create the mock that conforms to the interface like so:

```
class AlamofireManagerInterfaceMock<ResponseType: ResponseObjectSerializable> {
    var functionsCalled = [String]()

    // MARK: - Input Variables
    var forURLString: URLStringConvertible?
    var completionHandlerResponseValue: Response<ResponseType, NSError>?
    var shouldCallCompletion = false
    var withEncoding: ParameterEncoding?
    var withHeaders: [String: String]?
    var withMethod: Alamofire.Method?
    var withParameters: [String: AnyObject]?

    // MARK: - Return Values
}

extension AlamofireManagerInterfaceMock: AlamofireManagerInterface {
    func apiRequest<T: ResponseObjectSerializable>(withMethod method: Alamofire.Method,
         forURLString URLString: URLStringConvertible,
         withParameters parameters: [String: AnyObject]? = nil,
         withEncoding encoding: ParameterEncoding = .URL,
         withHeaders headers: [String: String]? = nil,
         completion completionHandler: (Response<T, NSError> -> Void)) {

    // Parameter capturing - removed

    if let value = completionHandlerResponseValue {
        // Problem is here
        completionHandler(value)
    }
}
```

So my question is how to do I tell the compiler that my `completionHandlerResponeValue` should be the same type as the parameter to pass to the `completionHandler`?

I get an error here:

```
if let value = completionHandlerResponseValue {
    completionHandler(value)
    // Error: Cannot convert value of type 'Response<ResponseType, NSError>' 
    // to expected argument type 'Response<_, NSError>'
}
```

I've tried a large amount of things around type casting such as:

```
if let value = completionHandlerResponseValue as Response<T, NSError>
// Error: Cannot convert value of type 'Response<ResponseType, NSError>?'
// to type 'Response<_, NSError>' in coercion
```

Trying to cast the handler:

```
if let handler = completionHandler as (Response<ResponseType, NSError> -> Void)
// Error: Cannot convert value of type 'Response<T, NSError> -> Void' 
// to type 'Response<_, NSError> -> Void' in coercion
```

Optionally casting:

```
if let value = completionHandlerResponseValue as? Response<T, NSError> {
// Warning: Cast from 'Response<ResponseType, NSError>?' to unrelated 
// type 'Response<T, NSError>' always fails
    completionHandler(response)
}
```

Comment: Have you tried `if let value: Response<ResponseType, NSError> = completionHandlerResponseValue` ? When using generics, the compiler requires a defined type rather than relying on the inferred type of the assignment value.

Comment: The problem with that is the next line calls the generic completion handler. So even defining `value` as `Response<ResponseType, NSError>` (which can be inferred by swift as that is the same declaration) means that `completionHandler(value)` line will cause the first error listed.